# query where relation contains any object from array

Tags: android, parse-platform

Some time ago i tried to use a BaaS service (parse.com), now I want to make a query to fetch a result set where parse' table contained tag values as "tag1, tag2, tag2"

I found similar [question](https://www.parse.com/questions/query-where-relation-contains-any-object-from-array), but it doesn't work fo me, in my case I get row where TAG column equals one of tags item, but not contained one of them

```
        query.whereContainedIn("Tags", Arrays.asList("tag1", "tag2"));
```

If someone had same issue please help me resolve it or give a correct way to figure it out